# Kendo grid field value needs to be different than displayed text

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid in kendo with the following columns:

```
columns: [
{ field: "GroupId", hidden: true},
{ field: "Name", title: "Group Name"}, 
{ field: "Description", title: "Description"},
{ field: "Users.length", title: "Assigned Users" }]
```

The datasource has the schema:

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "GroupId",
        fields: {
            Name: {editable: true},
            Description: {editable: true},
            Users: {editable: false},
        }
    }
}
```

My problem: I do not want Users to be editable, so it has the editable: false property. But this doesn't seem to be binding to my Users.length field.

Which of the following is the correct/implementable approach to this? I'm new to kendo, so I've had no luck figuring this out on my own.

1. Can I have the field name refer to Users, and the display value be Users.length?
2. Can I bind the field in the schema to Users.length somehow?

Comment: You want the display text to be the length of the username and value a name??So if name is `John` display 4 and `John` is the value?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the field to whatever (not `Users.length`) you can actually not even defined field. Then show the content using a template. Something like:

```
columns: [
    { field: "GroupId", hidden: true},
    { field: "Name", title: "Group Name"}, 
    { field: "Description", title: "Description"},
    { title: "Assigned Users", template: "#= Users.length #" }
]
```

When you do not define `field` attribute, it automatically becomes not editable BUT you still have access to the fields of your model.